# angular2 ngif fails to hide html tags when false

Tags: angular, typescript

In the html file i have

```
<p *ngIf="!checklistsready">
  not redy
</p>


<p *ngIf="checklistsready">
  Ready
</p>
```

In my typescript file i have

```
checklistsready: boolean = false;


constructor(){
     this.fetchChecks();
   }


 fetchChecks(){
   this._checklistService.getAllchecks() //fetch data from http
     .subscribe(
         res=>{
             console.log(res) //this displays the output
                this.checklistsready = true;  
               }

        )

    }
```

What could be wriong since the page always displays not ready?

Comment: I think either the service isn't getting called or it is resolving outside an angular event loop.  Try injecting `ApplicationRef` and calling `tick()` on it after setting the list to true, or add a button and log the value of `checkslistsready` in the click handler, that will trigger a change detection round.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat do you have a sample example on how to call the tick method ive researched online and cant get any relevant example

Comment: Import [`ApplicationRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ApplicationRef)  from `@angular/core` and add it to your constructor `constructor(public applicationRef: ApplicationRef)`.  Then after setting your variable, call `this.applicationRef.tick()`

Comment: Thanks @JasonGoemaat It now works, You can also post it as an answer ill mark it as correct to help another person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either the service isn't getting called or it is resolving outside an angular event loop. Try injecting ApplicationRef and calling tick() on it after setting the list to true, or add a button and log the value of checkslistsready in the click handler, that will trigger a change detection round.

```
import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core'
```

In the controller:

checklistsready: boolean = false;

```
constructor(public applicationRef: ApplicationRef) {
  this.fetchChecks();
}

fetchChecks() {
  this._checklistService.getAllchecks() //fetch data from http
    .subscribe(
      res=> {
        console.log(res) //this displays the output
        this.checklistsready = true;

        // trigger change detection
        this.applicationRef.tick();
      }
    )
}
```

Comment: I've run into similar CD issues. I'd expect the subscription callback to be getting called in the `NgZone`, which automatically triggers a CD cycle once completed, and I'm not certain but I believe it does in fact get run within `NgZone` but at a different phase (perhaps after `onMicrotaskEmpty` somehow?). My solution is generally to use `Subject` fields with `async` pipes (e.g., `public checklistsready$ = new BehaviorSubject(false);` --> `*ngIf="checklistsready$ | async"`), which also facilitates the `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` strategy which may improve performance in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is causing the problem, but it's bad practice to put asynchronous code in a constructor. Instead, have your component implement `OnInit` and fetch your data in the `ngOnInit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try Specifying an actual statement in ngIf.  Like so

```
*ngIf="!checklistsready == true"
```

Comment: This being JavaScript, that's entirely unnecessary

Comment: @Hammer writing it the way you suggest will result in much repetation and since the checklistsready property is a boolean type hence no need of comparison,